# Is the tensor $T^{i}_{\;j}{}^{\,k}$ the same as the tensor $T^{ik}_{\;\;j}$, and why would it be written as the former, if so?

Tags: tensors, index-notation

Sometimes I see contravariant and covariant indices of tensors interspersed, like, for example, $T^{i}_{\;j}{}^{\,k}$, but, as far as I currently understand, only the position of covariant indices with respect to other covariant indices, and contravariant indices with respect to contravariant, affects the behaviour of the tensor.

Is there any common purpose/benefit/meaning in interspersing indices of tensors? Should I interpret the tensor $T^{i}_{\;j}{}^{\,k}$ any differently than I would without the interspersed indices, $T^{ik}_{\;\;j}$?

Comment: Do you ever "raise and lower" indices? I know they do that a lot in general relativity.

Comment: Yes, but I see this notation without any raising/lowering of indices occurring (supposedly). Are you suggesting, in the example I gave, the $j$ was raised, $k$ lowered, and each relabelled, and the purpose of the interspersing to keep track of the 'identity' of each index?

Comment: No, I was suggesting that just raising $j$ in each case would give you three covariant indices in different order, so by your own admission different tensors.

Comment: True! I haven't learned about raising and lowering indices yet, though I'm aware it can be done, so this didn't occur to me. Thank you! This suggests there is a meaningful difference.

Comment: "Raising and lowering indices" roughly corresponds to what standard linear algebra calls "taking the transpose". However, transposing simultaneously raises _all_ contravariant indices and lowers _all_ covariant indices (and in linear algebra, there is at most one free index of each type anyways). Also, transposing doesn't take the metric into account. So it's not exactly the same, but it's close.